# Flex : Use custom background skin on datagrid header for currently sorted column

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, flex-datagrid, flex-skins

I use a flex mx:datagrid. I can set the headerBackgroundSkin to specify a skin or a picture to be displayed in all datagrid column's headers and it works just fine !

The problem is I can't find any way to specify a custom skin for the currently sorted column (doesn't matter if the sort is asc or desc, this is just to show the user which column is currently sorted).

I also tried to create a custom headerRenderer for each column but it is quite complicated and doesn't work very well.

I have been looking for the solution for a while but I can't find a good approach to do it. It sounds like a very basic need for me...incredible it is so complicated to achieve with Flex !!

I noticed someone was looking for the same thing few years ago but without success...
http://groups.google.com/group/flex_india/msg/78564c365c487583

If anyone has a solution or a workaround I would appreciate a lot !

Thanks in advance
Kim

[Flex]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'skin' for the column, however, you could change the `backgroundColor` style on the column itself when the user clicks to sort on the column itself.  If you want something more complex, you will have to extend the Datagrid itself to do it.

Comment: That's also my conclusion...but this is incredible how simple things can become very complicated with flex...

Comment: "simple" is relative.  The charting components are a particular exception because they were made to 'just work' out of the box with data and didn't take customization much into consideration.  The new charting components will be much better for this.

Answer (score -1):

If you only change backgroundColor it has no effect on header